# How to tab through multiple textField inputs when return key is pressed?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a form with multiple inputs inside of FormController. Whenever a user presses the return key, I want it to tab the cursor over to the next textField without closing and reopening the keyboard. However, the textField input is inside of a wrapper class textFieldContainer that adds customization to the text field. This class is also used elsewhere in the project so I don't want to edit this class. I'm new to Swift so I want to know how I can implement the textFieldShouldReturn function from within the FormController class.

I have researched this question and I have the implementation of textFieldShouldReturn down but I do not know where to put it. I think it will involve tags on each of the textFields and cycling through the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this? 
You should be able to assign a tag for those created textfields and then use the followiung code.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let txtTag:Int = textField.tag    
    if let next = self.view.viewWithTag(txtTag+1) as? UITextField {
        next.becomeFirstResponder()
    }else{
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    return true
}
```

Or something very similar to this should do it.

Comment: I have tried this but since FormController is using textFieldContainer's and not UITextField's it doesn't work.

Comment: you must be able to access the underlying textfields.. or do you a recursive function to find  childviews. Thats the way to do it.

Comment: I can access the text fields with emailTextField.textField, but I don't know how to implement the textFieldShouldReturn function in the FormController so that it works

Comment: Just put the function in the class? Or under viewWillAppear, or where?

Comment: hm.. if you can access the textfields, can't you pass the delegates and tags to them too? form.textfield.delegate = self in that fashion?

Comment: I ended up solving it by creating a delegate for the textFieldContainer with a function called shouldReturnKeyPressTab and then using it in FormController. Then I told shouldReturnKeyPress to use the delegate for the function.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it by creating a delegate for the textFieldContainer with a function called shouldReturnKeyPressTab and then using it in FormController. Then I told shouldReturnKeyPress to use the delegate for the function.